# vc60.pdb hell with Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++

We have a C++ 6.0 (stuck there for many reasons) application that uses COM heavily, and I have one of the COM servers (an EXE) that loads 5 or 6 DLLs.  In attempting to debug this monstrosity, I get a pop-up on the first breakpoint that demands I "enter the path for vc60.pdb."  The file is in both the source folder and the executable folder, but MS insists "A file with the correct name was found in this directory, but it is not the correct one."

I have verified the copy in both folders IS the copy that is created when the project is built, so I don't know where the "correct one" it is asking for is hiding.  Of course, without this file, debugging is almost useless, as you can not view any symbols other than local integers, etc.  Even custom classes defined within the project itself cannot be viewed.

Anyone know of (or if there is) a way around compiler stupidity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you debugging in VC6, or what debugger are you using?

Comment: I didn't know you could debug Visual C++ with anything else (short answer: Yes)

Comment: You can debug *anything* with [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx) and it has the option to allow mismatched symbols (`.symopt+0x40`). Or maybe you could try [ChkMatch](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/chkmatch.html) though I don't have first hand experience with it.